# How can I make the body fill the entire available space, not just the screen?

Tags: html, css, position, positioning

I have a sidebar, which I would like to be positioned completely to the right of the body, no matter how zoomed in the screen is. So if the screen is at 100% zoom, it should be lined up with the right border of the screen, but the more I zoom in, it should slowly be hidden as it moves rightwards along with the right border of the body.

How can I accomplish this? As my code is now, the sidebar stays perfectly aligned with the screen's right border no matter how much I zoom in. So if I zoom in and then scroll right, a large amount of white space is revealed between the sidebar and the right border of the body.

```
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  position: relative;
  right: 0%;
}
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML?

Comment: @Siyah I'm just trying to get it work at the most basic level at this point, so right now all I have is `<div id="sidebar">Test</div>`.

Comment: I put the code that you provided, with "all the html" you said you have inside a jsfiddle, so, where is your error ? http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/2zukk5r8/

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on with that jsfiddle; the sidebar isn't even on the right side of the page. But my problem is that when I zoom in, the sidebar should move rightward along with the body's right border, but instead it stays lined up with the screen's right border.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so, with only this :

CSS:

```
body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
    background:blue;
}
#sidebar {
  position: relative;
  right: 0%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar">Test</div>
```

The sidebar CAN'T BE on the right side of the page. It's impossible. To make it stick on the right side of the window you need it like this :

CSS:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:blue;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background:white;
}
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/2zukk5r8/1/):

**BUT I GUESS THIS IS WHAT YOU ARE LOOKING FOR:**
If you want this to be a sidebar and still have it positioned relative, you need a main content, and a wrapper. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/2zukk5r8/2/).

CSS:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background:blue;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#wrapper{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
}
#content{
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:yellow;
}
#sidebar {
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background:white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">CONTENT</div>
<div id="sidebar">SIDEBAR</div>
</div>
```

I took a wild guess on the last one thinking this is what you will want to end up doing. In this, even if you zoom/shrink your window and you scroll right, you will see the blue background all the way. No white areas.

Comment: What I am trying to do is get the sidebar to ALWAYS stick to the right border of the body. No matter what part of the body is being viewed, or how zoomed in/out the view is, the sidebar should constantly be pushed as far right as the body can go. If I can only see the left half of the body, I shouldn't be able to see the sidebar at all. And if I zoom in all the way and scroll right as far as I can, the sidebar should extend all the way to the right of my screen. I hope that's clear.

Comment: @user3739453 My friend, you are misusing HTML ? The <body> tag defines the document's body. The <body> element contains all the contents of an HTML document, such as text, hyperlinks, images, tables, lists, etc. Therefore the body CONTAINS your sidebar. I'm afraid you are confusing the body with the role the <div id="content"></div> has in my last example.

Comment: Then what is the term for the entire area that is possible to be viewed? In other words, if you zoom as far as possible, and then scroll until the page stops scrolling in all four directions, even if you scroll outside of the body; what is the term for that whole area?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
    html { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; }
    body { min-height: 100%; }
```